# How can I can get tha range of value, if the value is in the range the result is true else false

Tags: vb.net

How can I can get tha range of value, if the value is in the range the result is true else false. Example first given value is 5 and second given number is 8. If the I input 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 the output is PASSED but if its not in the range ouput will be FAILED.

Try

```
        If CDbl(TextBox16.Text) > CDbl(TextBox13.Text) And CDbl(TextBox16.Text) > CDbl(TextBox14.Text) Then

            TextBox17.Text = "FAILED"
        Else
            TextBox17.Text = "PASSED"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(" Required Complete LCR Specification!", "Invalid Process", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        TextBox16.Focus()

    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If CDbl(TextBox16.Text) < CDbl(TextBox13.Text) Or CDbl(TextBox16.Text) > CDbl(TextBox14.Text) Then
    TextBox17.Text = "FAILED"
Else
    TextBox17.Text = "PASSED"
End If
Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show(" Required Complete LCR Specification!", "Invalid Process", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
    TextBox16.Focus()

End Try
```

I think this will work.
Your TextBox13 should contains starting number and TextBox14 should contain ending number

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
TextBox1.Text=5
TextBox2.Text=8

 If CDbl(TextBox3.Text) >= CDbl(TextBox1.Text) And CDbl(TextBox3.Text) <= 
 CDbl(TextBox2.Text) Then
            MsgBox("Passed")
 Else
            MsgBox("failed")
 End If
```